# Magento display all categories in a separate view all page

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magento.
I have created a module to display all categories in a separate page, but i struggling to connect with category table to retrieve all categories and display all categories in a separate page. 
I have to give a link to view all categories in home page. So that all categories will be listed..

Can anyone help  me to do this??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all categories of a store:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$categoryCollection = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false);
if(is_object($categoryCollection) && $categoryCollection->count()):

?>
    <h3><?php echo $this->__('Categories'); ?></h3>
    <ul class="sub-cat">
        <?php foreach($categoryCollection as $_item): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getItemUrl($_item) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->name) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->name) ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php
endif;

?>
```

Comment: I want to retrieve this category list from block then i wnt to print in view page.

Comment: so you can put first two lines in block function and call from template file

Comment: okay.. I got it.. Thanks.. But I want to separate main category and sub category to print tree structure..